# the exception:boto.https_connection.InvalidCertificateException: Host storage.googleapis.com returned an invalid certificate

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, bucket

I use boto to create bucket. But there appears the problem:
the dump information:

```
File "train.py", line 111, in <module>
    main()
  File "train.py", line 48, in main
    train(args)
  File "train.py", line 51, in train
    data_loader = TextLoader(args.data_dir, args.batch_size, args.seq_length)
  File "/Users/sun/workspace/word-rnn-tensorflow/utils.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.preprocess(input_file, vocab_file, tensor_file)
  File "/Users/sun/workspace/word-rnn-tensorflow/utils.py", line 106, in preprocess
    uri.create_bucket(headers=header_values)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/storage_uri.py", line 563, in create_bucket
    storage_class)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/gs/connection.py", line 95, in create_bucket
    data=get_utf8_value(data))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 668, in make_request
    retry_handler=retry_handler
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1071, in make_request
    retry_handler=retry_handler)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 943, in _mexe
    request.body, request.headers)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1053, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1093, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1049, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 893, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 855, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/https_connection.py", line 138, in connect
    'certificate' % hostname)
boto.https_connection.InvalidCertificateException: Host storage.googleapis.com returned an invalid certificate (remote hostname "storage.googleapis.com" does not match certificate): {'crlDistributionPoints': (u'http://pki.google.com/GIAG2.crl',), 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', '*.google.com'), ('DNS', '*.android.com'), ('DNS', '*.appengine.google.com'), ('DNS', '*.cloud.google.com'), ('DNS', '*.google-analytics.com'), ('DNS', '*.google.ca'), ('DNS', '*.google.cl'), ('DNS', '*.google.co.in'), ('DNS', '*.google.co.jp'), ('DNS', '*.google.co.uk'), ('DNS', '*.google.com.ar'), ('DNS', '*.google.com.au'), ('DNS', '*.google.com.br'), ('DNS', '*.google.com.co'), ('DNS', '*.google.com.mx'), ('DNS', '*.google.com.tr'), ('DNS', '*.google.com.vn'), ('DNS', '*.google.de'), ('DNS', '*.google.es'), ('DNS', '*.google.fr'), ('DNS', '*.google.hu'), ('DNS', '*.google.it'), ('DNS', '*.google.nl'), ('DNS', '*.google.pl'), ('DNS', '*.google.pt'), ('DNS', '*.googleadapis.com'), ('DNS', '*.googleapis.cn'), ('DNS', '*.googlecommerce.com'), ('DNS', '*.googlevideo.com'), ('DNS', '*.gstatic.cn'), ('DNS', '*.gstatic.com'), ('DNS', '*.gvt1.com'), ('DNS', '*.gvt2.com'), ('DNS', '*.metric.gstatic.com'), ('DNS', '*.urchin.com'), ('DNS', '*.url.google.com'), ('DNS', '*.youtube-nocookie.com'), ('DNS', '*.youtube.com'), ('DNS', '*.youtubeeducation.com'), ('DNS', '*.ytimg.com'), ('DNS', 'android.clients.google.com'), ('DNS', 'android.com'), ('DNS', 'developer.android.google.cn'), ('DNS', 'g.co'), ('DNS', 'goo.gl'), ('DNS', 'google-analytics.com'), ('DNS', 'google.com'), ('DNS', 'googlecommerce.com'), ('DNS', 'policy.mta-sts.google.com'), ('DNS', 'urchin.com'), ('DNS', 'www.goo.gl'), ('DNS', 'youtu.be'), ('DNS', 'youtube.com'), ('DNS', 'youtubeeducation.com')), 'notBefore': u'Oct 26 10:09:57 2016 GMT', 'caIssuers': (u'http://pki.google.com/GIAG2.crt',), 'OCSP': (u'http://clients1.google.com/ocsp',), 'serialNumber': u'151FC9ADB8F5FF10', 'notAfter': 'Jan 18 09:56:00 2017 GMT', 'version': 3L, 'subject': ((('countryName', u'US'),), (('stateOrProvinceName', u'California'),), (('localityName', u'Mountain View'),), (('organizationName', u'Google Inc'),), (('commonName', u'*.google.com'),)), 'issuer': ((('countryName', u'US'),), (('organizationName', u'Google Inc'),), (('commonName', u'Google Internet Authority G2'),))}
```

I have search some solutions on google , and I try to add code as follows in to my local .boto file ,but it did not work.

```
[s3]
calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat
host = s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```